# What happens if corePoolSize of ThreadPoolExecutor is 0

Tags: threadpoolexecutor

I'm reading Efficient Android Threading.
It says,

> With zero-core threads and a bounded queue that can hold 10 tasks, no tasks actually run until the 11th task is inserted, triggering the creation of a thread.

But when I try code such as,

```
    int N = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            0,
            N*2,
            60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10));

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; ++i) {

        final int j = i;

        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Debug", "Executed : " + j);
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            }
        });

        Log.d("Debug", "Queued : " + i);

    }
```

The tasks are executed correctly even though there are only 5 tasks in the queue. What am I missing ?